# are all nodes validate each transaction added in a new block?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, blockchain

are all nodes validate each transaction added in a new block?

Because what if someone said I have completed block and added invalid transaction? and if others node just accepts a block without validating a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are all nodes validate each transaction added in a new block?

Yes, each full node checks each transaction and block to make sure they are valid according to the network rules.